# NextJS application is not displaying site on Azure AppService

Tags: docker, next.js, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy my NextJS application, to AppService. But I need to dockerize it first.
If I try the docker configuration locally, it works, but at the moment to deploy it on azure, I get the page:

[image]

My logs:

```
Azure Web App on Container Deploy

Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'myapplicationMYWEBAPPRESOURCE'
Single-container Deployment to the webapp 'myapplicationMYWEBAPPRESOURCE' as only the image detail was specified.
Trying to update App Service Configuration settings. Data: {"appCommandLine":null,"windowsFxVersion":"DOCKER|CMYACR/myapplication-app:3677087"}
Updated App Service Configuration settings.
Restarting App Service: myapplicationMYWEBAPPRESOURCE
App Service 'myapplicationMYWEBAPPRESOURCE' restarted successfully.
Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight : myappinsight
Successfully updated deployment History at https://myapplicationMYWEBAPPRESOURCE.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/36770871678028437889
```

My Pipeline:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: "Build Image"
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: MY-ACR
    repository: myapplication-app
    command: "build"
    Dockerfile: "$(project.dockerfile.path)"
    arguments: '--build-arg ACCESS_TOKEN="$(System.AccessToken)"'
    tags: "$(Build.BuildId)"

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: "Push Image: DEV"
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: MY-ACR
    repository: myapplication-app
    command: "push"
    tags: "$(Build.BuildId)"

- task: AzureWebAppContainer@1
  displayName: 'Azure Web App on Container Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.azureServiceConnection }}
    appName: $(myapplication-app.webappName)
    imageName: MY-ACR/myapplication-app:$(Build.BuildId)
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

ENV PORT=8080

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./

FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN yarn build

FROM node:18-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ARG AUTH_URL
ARG AUTH_SECRET

ENV NODE_ENV production

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 8080

ENV PORT 8080

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And in my resource, I just can see:

```
023-03-05T15:16:13.522Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for 10.x.x.x:13209/appsvc/node:18-lts_20221208.1.tuxprod
2023-03-05T15:16:13.526Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2023-03-05T15:16:13.547Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2023-03-05T15:16:13.548Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name myappservice_6_d637d294 -e WEBSITES_PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=myappservice -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=myappservice.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=03162c5fb5bcdbeba70ac60be15b5262381392b93b18ebea9a3965fdf0c88c55 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=True appsvc/node:18-lts_20221208.1.tuxprod
2023-03-05T15:16:14.711Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container myappservice_6_d637d294 for site myappservice
2023-03-05T15:16:16.735Z INFO  - Container myappservice_6_d637d294 for site myappservice initialized successfully and is ready to serve requests.
```

I can't see any errors in my logs, also during my pipeline build or deploy.
The application is running on the port 8080.
The buildid (tag) matchs in my overview.
But my page is not loading.
Does someone has an idea about how troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your requirement by taking sample Next js application, I was facing same issue as you mentioned.

Also, I have changed the default port number from 3000 to 8080 in Package.json.

```json
"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev -p 8080",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start -p 8080"
}
```

I wrote a pipeline to build and deploy a docker image of my application to Azure App Service.

I found that we have to configure `WEBSITES_PORT` in Azure App service.
To configure `WEBSITES_PORT`, Go to your App Service ->settings->configuration-> Application Settings-> click on New Application Settings, add the WEBSITES_PORT and port number as shown below:
[image]

***Before** Adding the configuration `WEBSITES_PORT:8080`:*

[image]

***After** Adding the configuration `WEBSITES_PORT:8080`:*

[image]